# Plotting a confidence band around a loess regression curve in R

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, data-visualization, loess

I have done a multiple linear regression with R. When I plot the diagnostics graphs, I would like to draw a confidence band along with the loess curve in the residual vs. fitted values plot.

How can I do that with R?

Comment: Notice that "how can I do whatever in whichever software" is considered off topic here, you question may be moved to another site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R, but without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of the possibilities:

```
library(ggplot2)

m01 <- lm(dist~speed, data=cars)
yhat <- m01$fit
resid <- m01$res

qplot(yhat, resid, geom=c("point", "smooth"), span=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem. geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is <1000, so using loess. Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.How can I do ?